# how i can save data to external phpmyadmin in asp.net and vb.net?

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, vb.net

I work in Project in ASP.NET Using VB.NET 
 using MySql.Data.MySqlClient to Connect with my DB in PHPMYADMIN Using localhost by xxmap .. all function like add , drop , update .. its work fine

but me question .. how i can implement Connection Between My VB.NET Code and between Online Host like ?

when i write this code :

```
"server=mysql.hostinger.ae; user=*****;password=*****;Database=****;"
```

Show me a problem Message : Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts

I search for the cause of the problem The result is : the Most Hosts do not support this type of connection? why ? and how i can Save my Data in PHPmyadmin in the Online Phpmyadmin ?

Comment: Don't connect directly, use a service layer like php to communicate with database..

Comment: ok thanks , can you tell me how i can connection between vb.net and php ? please

Comment: the PHP layer idea is a good one. Write your PHP like an API, accepting and returning JSON, then call it from VB.NET using a client library like HttpClient

Comment: P.S. You can't save data in PhpMyAdmin. PhpMyAdmin is just a GUI tool (one of many) which lets you interact with a MySQL database. It's useful to use the right terminology. What you want say is "save data in MySql"